# Get length of videos calling youtube playlist API (v3)

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

```js
$http.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=PLFgquLnL59alCl_2TQvOiD5Vgm1hCaGSI&key={mykey}&maxResults=10")
```

I used the `playlistItems` but couldn't get the statistic part which contain duration of the video. Do I need to call twice? Get the video Id and make another call? or I'm missing something in this case?

Comment: You wouldn't find it because it's in the contentDetails part not snippet.

I have given an answer that shows how it can be obtained.

Answer (score 2):

For whatever reason, `playlistItems` do not include some things like statistics or category. You'll need to make a separate call using the video ID and `https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list` in order to get those fields.

Comment: using the video id where?

Comment: I got them. I will answer later

Comment: @johnj10 I have answered it now

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it (using Python but you can adapt it for whatever language you are using with http requests and JSON parsing)

```
 url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=" + videoId 
     + "&key=" + DEVELOPER_KEY + "&part=snippet,contentDetails"
 r = requests.get(url)
 metadata = r.json()["items"][0]
 channelName = metadata["snippet"]["channelTitle"]
 publishedTime = metadata["snippet"]["publishedAt"]
 duration = metadata["contentDetails"]["duration"]
```

duration is in a strange format that looks like

```
 PT4M11S
```

meaning 4 minutes 11 seconds. You will have to "parse" this.